# Manually re-enable wireless and bluetooth

Tags: 12.04, wireless, bluetooth

So, today, I decided to **turn off** bluetooth to save battery power. When I did so, it did everything like normal. Whatever. But whenever I want to **re-enable** Wifi and Bluetooth, it just has "Enable Wireless" and "Enable bluetooth" **grayed out** in the respective things on the top-right of the desktop. I am using 12.04 Precise Pangolin on a Dell laptop that has never had wireless problems before. Clicking the grayed-out part does nothing. Re-logging and restarting has no effect, and I'm on an account that has full administrative permission.

My attempts:

```
~$ sudo dmesg | grep wlan0
[19.960211] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
```

.

```
~$ sudo dmesg | grep blue
```

[[nothing]]

What do I do to manually re-enable wireless and bluetooth?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found that under my "Bluetooth settings", I couldn't click anything and it said it was disabled by hardware switch.

So, I looked at my keyboard, and there's kind of this radio tower over "F2" in the color of the FN button. So I pressed FN-F2 and it re-enabled wireless and bluetooth.

I don't even remember pressing that button ever before, but I pressed it, and it worked.

**Future viewers: If you see that your wireless AND bluetooth are disabled, and you're on a laptop, press FN-(wireless button, for example mine was F2). This will likely solve your problems.**

What a simple solution. Really surprised this solution hasn't come up in any other Ask pages I've seen so far.

If this doesn't work, try the console commands:

```
sudo service wireless start
sudo service bluetooth start
```

as those returned neutral or favorable results for me, regardless of the button being down or not.

Comment: Nice man, glad to see that your issue was solved! And have to note that I had faced issues like that in the past successfully. It is surprising that it didn't strike me this time.

Comment: Yeah, I know, it is such an obvious answer to such a simple question. We really overthought it.

I did look it up though. Apparently, in Ubuntu 12.04 (and this is apparently not very common, I saw maybe 1 or 2 forum posts about it), turning off bluetooth switches the hardware switch for the wireless button, because I NEVER pressed that button. It may be my computer model or something. But all I clicked was bluetooth and bam. Whatever. Problem solved. Hope I help someone else quicker than I helped myself xD

Comment: Mark your answer as accepted so people can see the solution if they face the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

I installed Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS few days ago (I was using Mint 10 earlier) and I have identical problem.

The icon says bluetooth is on, but there aren't any options and in bluetooth settings it says it's disabled.

I found the solution working for me:

```
sudo service bluetooth restart
```

I simply restarted the service, and it started working immediately!

My laptop is Samsung NP300E5A, Intel Centrino Wireless-N 130 (WiFi & BT).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**For networking**:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking start
```

**For the bluetooth:**

```
sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth start
```

If the above do not work, you have to check if the kernel recognises the modules properly (which I assume it does, since you have used it before) by using:

```
dmesg | grep blue
```

and

```
dmesg | grep wlan0
```

Comment: for networking, it returned "Rather than invoking init scripts through . . . . " and gave me a suggestion of a command to do instead. I did that, and it said "rejected send message, 1 matched rules;" and a bunch more

AKA, doesn't work

Comment: Okay. So, "sudo service wireless start" returned "networking stop/waiting". I dunno what that means.

And "dmesh | grep wlan0" returned "[     19.960211] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): **wlan0**: link is not ready"

bold was in red

Bluetooth is allegedly working on the console.
'sudo service bluetooth start
start: job is already running: bluetooth'

Comment: Are you able to use wireless connectivity now?

Comment: No. Bluetooth is still disabled, too. According to the thingie in the top-right

Comment: Can u type dmesg | grep wlan and dmesg | grep bluetooth and paste the output in your question?

Comment: OH! Okay. Well, we didn't need any command line. I found out how to fix it. Going to add my own answer xD